# get all file path from request in java

Tags: java, file-upload, inputstream, absolute-path, input-type-file

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>File Upload</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        File:
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> <br/>
        Destination:
        <input type="text" value="/tmp" name="destination"/>
        </br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" id="upload" />
    </form>
</body>
```

I want to get all file path which is chosen via browser(input type="file") to upload it to ftp server.

I had found a lot of code snaps but just they give me file name I need absolute path such as "c:\users\filename".

Thank yo for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reason, browsers do not provide you full/absolute path for any file.